# docker ps shows stopped containers too

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. I tried executing the docker run command on busybox, and tried to ping facebook.com
But even when I exited the action using *ctrl+c*, the container still shows up when I run **docker ps**.
Has the container not stopped and still running? I had to stop the container using **docker stop**.
But why does the container seems to be running even after exiting the ping command?

Here's what my command line shows -
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GpiL.png)

Comment: please put text in the question, not screenshot.  they're not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are running it in wrong way if you want your container should stop and get's removed after the process completion then run the command like this

```
 docker run -it --rm busybox ping facebook.com
```

`-it` means interactive and `-rm` does remove